# How to create dynamic autoincrement buttons and labels

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created submenu buttons dynamic after click that button i get some data from sql server to html table(automatic updation). My Problem is how to generate labels and buttons dynamically after click Submenu dynamic button. I need answer in asp.net and c#. can anyone help for my question?  How to create dynamic autoincrement  buttons and labels using asp.net with c#?